# woocommerce shop page, how to add custom price via "add to cart" button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I can add a text box on the product page, which allows the user enter a custom price and the product is added to the cart with the custom price fine.

My question is how do I do the same thing on the shop page?
I want to add a text box for each item on the shop page and allow users to enter a custom price.
On the shop page, I can add the text box for user to enter a custom price, but how do I transfer that price to the cart when user presses on the "Add to cart" button??

The issue is that the button on the shop page is an href tag and its not an actual form submit.

I've tried the woocommerce "woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation" hook but that doesn't work b/c by the time it gets here, I've lost the data from the shop page.
Is there a different hook for the shop page's "add to cart" button?
Is there a hook to save my information from shop page to the session?
If I have to change woocommerce page, which page should it be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking, here is how I resolved this issue.

1. I enclosed my text box and "add to cart" button in a form tag ( with method="post") using hook, add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'function',8 ). Order must be between 5 & 10 (in this case 8), bc we want it ran between the 2 functions already hooked.  You MUST add a specific "id" attribute for each form, so that later you can refer to a specific form using jQuery. I chose to add the number of the product as a part of the id. For example, I would use id="formID_42" where 42 was the number of the product (from $product->get_id() )
2. I changed the file "add-to-cart.php" to basically create a submit button (input tag with type=submit) instead of the default href tag.
   I also used jQuery to update the form's (created in step 1) action attribute to redirect to correct "add to cart" url for the specific product (ie: action="?add-to-cart=42" where 42 is the number of the product. get 42 using $product->get_id() )
3. Use hook, add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data'), to process the text box's data passed in from $_POST[] and save it to cart (same as if you're passing from the product's page.

Basically, put text box field and "add to cart" button inside a form tag.
When a user hits the "add to cart" button, the information in the text field is POST and you capture the POST data in the hook, add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data'), and process the data using $_POST[].  Save the custom price to cart like you would if you were on the Product page. If you want to know how to add custom price to cart, search will give you many answers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).